# About the Dispose pattern and the Finalizer in C#

Tags: c#, destructor, dispose, finalizer

First in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

there is a standard Dispose pattern. And there is a bool as the parameter of the protected `Dispose` method to tell the GC whether managed resources are freed manually already, so that the GC does not need to care about them.

Now the question is, what exactly should be done inside the `if (disposing) {}` block? Normally the GC cleans up managed resources, so one doesn't need to do anything special. But since inside this block, one needs to explicitly clean up managed resources, does that mean one just set all the fields and stuff in the object to `null`?

Second, isn't it just nicer to have just one destructor (or finalizer whatever it calls) in the language? And then in the GC design, just put a bit to determine if the destructor is already called so that there is no need to garbage collect it, or the destructor is not yet called and the GC should clean it up. I found the Dispose pattern quite complicated, and I am very confused what to clean up in which function and how to clean up in derived classed. And by using a signle destructor design, the GC just cleans things up when they are not cleaned up yet, and does not clean up when they are already.

Greetings

PS: So is this also a good and simpler pattern to clean up objects?

```
class Foo
{
    bool unmanagedDisposed = false;
    void Dispose() {/*clean up unmanaged resources*/ unmanagedDisposed = true;}
    ~Foo() {if (!unmanagedDisposed) Dispose();}
}
```

So if the programmer knows and remembers to call `Dispose()`, nothing to do in the finalizer, otherwise clean up unmanaged resources in the finalizer. And here we don't need to care about those managed resources.

Comment: Read this great article to fully understand the Dispose pattern. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About Quite complex on the first read but extremely instructive.

Comment: Imagine that one of your classes managed resources itself implements `IDisposable`. Where do you think you ought to call `Dispose()` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what exactly should be done inside the `if (disposing) {}` block?

You clean up the *managed* resources, ie you call `Dispose()` on all IDisposable objects that you own at that point.

> to explicitly clean up managed resources, does that mean one just set all the fields and stuff in the object to null?

No, it does not mean that. It's only about IDisposable objects.

> isn't it just nicer to have just one destructor (or finalizer whatever it calls) in the language?

We only have one destructor aka Finalizer and  `Dispose()` is not it. That makes the rest of your paragraph irrelevant.

We have the Disposable pattern and the GC, they are related and cooperating but not the same. The GC manages memory and only memory. IDisposable is for managing resources (stream, connections, bitmaps).

Comment: I always find the null-comparable-to-disposing idea a bizarre conclusion anyone would pick up by intuition

Comment: @henk-holterman Thanks for the concrete instruction about the `if (disposing){}` block! Anyway by the destructor or finalizer I mean putting all the destruction routine together, so that one does not need to care about a finalizer plus a dispose interface. I still need to make this clear by my onw.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you only need to implement the full `~Destructor()` pattern with dispose if you have a class that has unmanaged fields or properties.

If all of your fields and properties are managed and not disposable, then you do not need to implement IDisposable at all.

If one of your fields or properties are disposable, then you need to just implement the IDisposable pattern. You don't necessarily have to go the whole hog with the above pattern.

If in the last case you do have an unmanaged resource in a field or property (e.g. a native pointer to something, a database connection other than ADO or other managed connections) then .net has no idea how to clean it up when the garbage collector rolls around.

In this case, you need to consider two places where your object will be cleaned up. Either it will be cleaned up by the developer calling `Dispose()` like he should, or he'll forget. If he forgets, and you have a destructor, then it's put on a finalization queue.

This is where the `Dispose(disposing)` call comes in. 
If the developer is good and calls `Dispose()`, then you send in true so that the managed resources can be cleaned up as well.

If the developer has not called dispose and the poor object ends up on the finalization queue, then calling `Dispose()` on the managed objects will throw an exception because they don't exist anymore. So in this case you send in a False, so that the managed resources are skipped and avoid the exception. I'm not sure about this, but legends say that throwing an exception on the finalization queue quits the whole process and could even end the world. So don't do it.

Comment: Caveat to "If one of your fields or properties are disposable..." paragraph - if the class isn't `sealed` (unfortunately, not the default), and you're implementing disposable, you should go the whole hog because you don't know what derived classes will need or do.

Comment: @MiketheTike Thanks for your clear answer, I do have a better understanding after reading your answer. So I think the finalizer just ensures that the unmanaged resources are cleaned up no matter the programmer calls `Dispose` or not. And since one would also clean managed resources together with the unmanaged ones, we need to separately handle the managed resources in the `Dispose` and the finalizer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: That was Microsoft's thinking when they first wrote the `Dispose` pattern.  In practice, however, if the base class doesn't encapsulate any unmanaged resources derived classes shouldn't either.  Any unmanaged resources they might need should be encapsulated in their own finalizable classes (possibly nested within the derived class), which the derived class could then use as a *managed* resource.